# Mechanism that moves two parts linear to each other

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I'm designing a machine that will seal plastic tubes. The idea is to clamp the tube with two beams. These two beams have to move away to let a piece of the tube through, then those beams should move to each other so that the plastic tube gets folded and hold between the two beams. One beam moves exactly the same as the other, only in the reverse direction. 
Currently, the design uses timing belts to accomplish this, but I'm searching for other ways to accomplish this type of movement, but I'm having a hard time finding mechanisms like this on the internet because I don't know how to call it. Is there a name for this kind of mechanism/movement? Or do you know any other ways to accomplish this movement?

Some illustrations that might clarify my explanation:
[image]
[image]

Another way I came up with is using a ball screw mechanism where one half of the axle has it's screw tapped the other way around, but that part is probably expansive to built. An rack and pinion system with two racks would also work. Other alternatives I came up with all use two motors.

Comment: the timing belt one is quite close to the belt system elevator doors use. It works, take a closer look at those. Pullies work too. In screw mechanism you dobt need the screw tapped differently just a different connection. There is a few ways to do this with bar mechanisms too what is yoir motive power?

Comment: The screw mechanism can work with two axles yes, but with one axle half of the screw should be tapped the other way right? I think bar mechanisms will be to big to fit in the design space. What do you mean with motive power? The current prototpye uses a cheap 12v motor and draws about 1 amp (12 watt)

Comment: Yes but using a lathe or tap to do that shouldn't be all that expensive (that is if you have access to a machine shop, i could do one in a hour or so. If not then yes). Well things can be powered by engines that drive shafts, hydraulics and pneumatics, they ould be human powered or so. If youd had hydraulics then this would be quite the walk in the park. I think i can fit a bar mechanism in that space easily in dont need the shafts then at all, so i can in fact save some space. But it depends on lot of things

Comment: What about a scissor type mechanism with a linear actuator?

Comment: @SolarMike that would be a bar mechanism

Comment: @joojaa well, it may just be an example that the OP will understand easily - of course you could explain the mechanics of a 4 bar chain as that may work...

Comment: @SolarMike scissor type mechanism would indeed work, thanks for the tip! Does it have any advantages to the timing belt mechanism? To me, it seems like there are many moving parts

Comment: You did not limit the number of parts - you asked for ideas for alternatives...

Comment: Yes I know, the scissor mechanism would indeed be an alternative. I was following up on my question by asking if it has any advantages to use a bar mechanism.

Comment: you dont need the rails.